# What does the abbreviation "Tg. Ps.-J" mean?

Tags: aramaic

I'm writing a biblical Hebrew exegesis research paper and I'm struggling to understand what a particular abbreviation means: "Tg. Ps.-J." It's in the Word Biblical Commentary 6A on Deuteronomy. I've seen it before but it's quite important to the exegesis to know which manuscript this variant refers to.

I'm guessing it has something to do with Targums and Peshittas but can't find any specific information out there on what the J stands for.

Comment: English translation of Ps. J. and Onkelos on the Torah available [here](http://targum.info/targumic-texts/pentateuchal-targumim/); Aramaic texts of the targumim are available at the [Comprehensive Aramaic Lexicon](http://cal.huc.edu/searching/targumsearch.html) as well as from [Logos.com](https://www.logos.com/product/7862/the-targums-from-the-files-of-the-comprehensive-aramaic-lexicon-project) and other e-retailers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tg. Ps. J stands for [Targum of Pseudo Jonathan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Pseudo-Jonathan). It is a [Targum](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14248-targum) of the western tradition, a translation of the Pentateuch. It is called Pseudo Jonathan because for years it was thought to be the work of [Jonathan b. Uzziel](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8776-jonathan-ben-uzziel). Most scholars conclude this is due to a printer's error. According to this opinion, the work was originally known as Targum Jerushalmi (Jerusalem) and abbreviated TJ (or TY). As the Jewish scholar Jonathan b. Uzziel did translate a targum (though of the [prophets](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14248-targum#anchor9) not the Pentateuch), the editions of TJ were assumed to be his by later readers (reading the TJ as Targum Jonathan). As the conclusion is against this now, the "Pseudo" (Ps) has been added in the references.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. I guess it's something you either know or you don't, and I didn't.